# Retrieving multiple rows using Pivot in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am having difficulty in understanding the below SQL query to pivot the table,

Table Name : Occupations

```
Name    | Occupation
-----------------
Sam     | Actor
Julia   | Singer
Ketty   | Actor
```

Expected result:

```
Actor   | Singer
----------------
Sam     | Julia
Ketty   | null
```

I got only one row, When I executed the below query,

```
Select [Actor],[Singer] From ( Select Occupation,Name From Occupations
 )sub Pivot (Max(Name) For Occupation in ([Actor],[Singer])) pvt
```

output :

```
Actor   | Singer
----------------
Sam | Julia
```

When I modified the above query using RowNumber(), I got the expected result(multiple rows).

```
 Select [Actor],[Singer] 
 From ( Select Occupation,Name,Row_Number() over(partition by Occupation order by Name)SNo
 From Occupations )sub
 Pivot (Max(Name) For Occupation in ([Actor],[Singer])) pvt
```

Can you explain , How adding Row_Number function in the sub query gives multiple row?

Comment: Your source data is insufficient to pivot, because there is no column which logically connects one actor to another singer.

Comment: Actually, I just want the list of Actor and Singer. If I execute the second query in the question I got the result, But I don't know how it works.

Comment: For this it would better to do google instead of asking the question, just checkout how `PIVOT` and `Row_Number()` works ?

Comment: @SuryaPrakash The Yogesh answer below should work for you then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Pivot` is a tricky syntax.  It returns one row for all the combination of columns *other* than the columns involved with the `pivot`.  When you do:

```
Select [Actor], [Singer] 
From (Select Occupation, Name,
      From Occupations
     ) sub
Pivot (Max(Name) For Occupation in ([Actor], [Singer])) pvt
```

There are *no* other rows.  Hence, one row is returned.

When you add:

```
row_Number() over (partition by Occupation order by Name) as sno
```

You now have another column that varies, and it is used (implicitly) by the `pivot`.

This awkward behavior is one reason why I prefer conditional aggregation to `pivot`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, This is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You want *conditional* aggregation :

```
select 
        max(case when Occupation = 'Actor' then Name end) [Actor],
        max(case when Occupation = 'Singer' then Name end) [Singer]
from (select *,
            row_number() over (partition by Occupation order by Name) Seq
      from table t
     ) t
group by Seq;
```

Since the above data model has no any grouping `column/field` based on that desired result achieve. So, you can generate the Sequence using analytical function and use them as in `GROUPING`.

Comment: Hi Yogesh, your query works fine. But I just want to achieve the same using pivot.

Comment: @SuryaPrakash... Your `pivot` query should also work.